# Heroku precompile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When pushing my rails app to heroku the precompile didn't work and now whenever I try to do anything (restart heroku, reset database, migrate database, rename heroku etc) I get this error:

Update: It seems Bundler isn't working locally on my laptop too.

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:52:in `initialize': Valid types are [:development, :runtime], not nil (ArgumentError)
from /Users/aaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:371:in `new'
from /Users/aaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:371:in `search'
from /Users/aaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:361:in `gems_size'
from /Users/aaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:159:in `start'
from /Users/aaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:159:in `map'
from /Users/aaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:159:in `start'
from /Users/aaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:128:in `resolve'
from /Users/aaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in `catch'
from /Users/aaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in `resolve'
from /Users/aaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:182:in `resolve'
from /Users/aaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:113:in `specs'
from /Users/aaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/environment.rb:27:in `specs'
from /Users/aaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.0/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:56:in `candidate?'
from /Users/aaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.0/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:74:in `setup'
from /Users/aaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.0/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:89
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /Users/aaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:9
```

This is what happened in the original push:

```
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   could not connect to server: Connection refused
   Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `initialize'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `new'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `connect'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:326:in `initialize'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__1193294461922673159__prepare__3401192585586483770__callbacks'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
   /tmp/build_13mv4cuh78fg0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
   Tasks: TOP => environment
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
   Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
```

I'd appreciate any help anyone could give in solving this issue.

Update: This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.9'
gem 'pg'
gem 'redis'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rails-i18n'
gem 'globalize3', '~> 0.2.0'
gem 'batch_translations', '~> 0.1.2'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

Comment: Can you please provide your Gemfile code?

Comment: @LeoCorrea I included my Gemfile above.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution here that looks somewhat like the problem you are having here

[Assets:precompile error heroku](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2012/02/heroku-and-rails-3-2-assetprecompile-error/)

It basically says to add this line `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` to your `application.rb` file. Apparently there was a problem with Rails 3.2 and Heroku. This might or might not solve your problem but it will narrow down the possibilities.

Also you might want to try adding the following in your Gemfile: `ruby "1.9.3"` right under the `source` line. Let me know if this works. Also make sure you run bundle install after you add that line.

Comment: Ok, I think there's something wrong with my rails environment. I can't run `bundle install` and running `bundle update` results in this error: `Could not find gem 'rails (= 1.9.3) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.` I think I'll just reinstall rails on my computer and see if that helps.

Comment: Are you using rvm or rbenv for your environment?

Comment: I'm using rvm. I seemed to have fixed the issue on my local machine by reinstalling rails but the original problem of pushing to heroku still persists.

Comment: its not solution to the problem as if you set precompile false heroku will give error of not precompiled assets.

Comment: @TaimoorChangaiz You realize that that's a solution that was given by Heroku right? It solves the problem for a lot of people including myself. Also, it won't give you that error if you precompile the assets before you push...

Comment: Ok you don't seem to understand. It's a solution given by the people that provide the service. Just because you say its not a good approach doesn't mean it doesn't solve the problem for a lot of people.

Comment: I am not sure why this was marked down. The solution here is the right fix for this. Rails 3.2 changes causes this error. I'm having the same issue.